# How to delete records in Accumulo based on an rowkey via Accumulo proxy client

Tags: node.js, proxy, accumulo

I'm using Accumulo 1.6 and want to delete some records by a giving rowkey via accumulo proxy client in nodejs.

but the proxy client throw "start row must be less than end row" when I trying to put same rowkey into the deleteRows API

```
var rowId = "1";
var proxyClient = getAccumuloProxyClient();
proxyClient.deleteRows(getLogin(), TABLE_NAME, rowId, rowId, callback);
```

**UPDATE:**
Let's say there is a table looks like:

```
rowID | columnFamily | columnQualifier
1        name           John
1        age            25
1        department     sales
2        name           Lisa
2        age            25  
2        department     sales
```

what parameters should I pass to the deleteRows function if I want to delete all of rows of rowID equals 1?
I tried pass 1 to start and end, but it complain

```
"org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloException: start row must be less than end row"
```

then I tried to pass `start = 1` and `end  = 1\0` to make sure start less than end, but nothing happend, no error threw, no rows deleted. 
I think that caused by the start is exclude and end is include for deleteRows. So I'm confused about how to delete one record(which rows has same rowID).

Comment: What is the specific version of Accumulo you're using?

Comment: @elserj I just using 1.6.0

Comment: I had initially thought you  might be hitting ACCUMULO-1994, but it appears not given the fixVersion

Comment: Can you provide examples of 'watchId' and 'END_SIGN' are in a failure case? I don't know of any bug that would cause this to fail. I would inspect the bytes of each string your provide in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you @elserj for your reply, Sorry about the confused example, please take a look the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: start =1 and end = 1\0 looks correct and should work as the API is specified. I'll try to look into it more specifically, there might be a subtle bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my case using (char - 1 as the start row is solved my problem:

```
var startRowId = rowId.substring(0, rowId.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(rowId.charCodeAt(rowId.length - 1) - 1);
proxyClient.deleteRows(getLogin(), TABLE_NAME, startRowId, rowId, callback);
```